# Text to Columns is getting a "method 'range' of object '_global' failed"

Tags: vba, excel

I took the macro code from using the "text to columns" wizard and put it in my code. But it's not working on a consistent basis.

I am getting "method 'range' of object '_global' failed" (sometimes)
I looked it up, and applied solutions, that either change nothing (it errors a few executions later)

The current attempt to specify it better has left me with

```
With Shipping
.ActiveSheet.Columns(letter & ":" & letter).TextToColumns Destination:=Range(letter & "1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 9), Array(3, 9), Array(4, 9)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
    True
End With
```

I have no idea if it wants me to specify better for the first half or the destination, which I can't find a solution for.

How do I make this work?

Comment: is `Shipping` a reference to a sheet? Also, check what is being to passed as `letter` when the macro fails. Short of that, can you post some sample data for us to play with?

Comment: What happens when you change `Range(letter & "1")` to `.ActiveSheet.Range(letter & "1")` ? I am assuming that `Shipping` is a workbook?

Comment: letter is just the resulting value of a function that finds the column letter of the sheet by the column header name. letter is equal to 'N' at this point int the code

Comment: I cannot post sample data. I could get in trouble for that. Shipping is a workbook.

Comment: try what @SiddharthRout says. I think the main issue is that depending on what `letter` is on any given run, it may crap out because it either can't find any data in that range to convert text on, or it is somehow passing through a letter, or combination of letters that is not an equivalent excel column. When you get that message, find out what `letter`'s value is (you said 'N'), and see what is in column N. You will probably find your problem from there.

Comment: I added `Shipping.Activate` right before the `With Shipping` line, and it crashed. While crashed, it does say the value of `letter` is N

Comment: Sorry - ignore my previous comment: I was wrong about the ActiveSheet issue. Rather than using (eg) `.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A")` why not use the simpler form `.ActiveSheet.Columns(1)` ?  **AND** add a period before `Range` in the Destination parameter, otherwise that range will default to the active sheet

Comment: Can you put that as an answer? It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using (eg) `.ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A")` why not use the simpler form `.ActiveSheet.Columns(1)` ?

And add a period before `Range` in the Destination parameter, otherwise that range will default to the active sheet.